# Select only first cell in first cell using Laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

Is there a method to select a first row cell in Laravel's query builder? Im looking for something like this:

```
$my_value = DB::table("my_table")
    ->select("value")
    ->where("key", "=", "my_key")
    ->getFirstRowCellValueOnly()
```

Yea, I could do it by selecting first row and then just selecting key "value" from returned array (`->first()["value"]`), but a default method would be more tidier ^ ^.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, the method is called `pluck()`.

```
$my_value = DB::table("my_table")
    ->select("value")
    ->where("key", "=", "my_key")
    ->pluck("value"); // same as in the select
```

Comment: Yes, it will return null if it doesn't work. And for Eloquent, it doesn't return anything at all if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I know its old, but still - The query builder have a handy method called `value`. This is actually what you are looking for.

```php
// The value of column_1 of the first matched result where column_2 is 'somthing'
$my_value = DB::table("my_table")
    ->where("column_2", "=", "something")
    ->value("column_1")
```

And it also works with models

```php
$my_value = MyModel::where("column_2", "=", "something")->value("column_1")
```